# Issue with Anaconda installation

Tags: linux, anaconda3

I had previously installed ananconda and it was working fine but suddenly the Ubuntu gives busy box error so I had to run manual fsck command after starting the Anaconda stopped working.

ananconda -command not found.

I checked the bashrc file the PATH exported is anaconda3/bin but when I run echo $PATH it gives *anaconda3/condabin*. How do I resolve it.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi

fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to remove the anaconda3/condabin from the $PATH variable.

```
export PATH=${PATH%:/home/YOUR_USER/anaconda3/condabin}
```

Comment: I removed the same from bashrc file. Installed fresh copy but again the same path comes in PATH.

Comment: I just checked my $PATH and i also have ~/anaconda3/condabin but it works fine for me so that can't be the issue. Could you give me the whole output of `echo $PATH` because right now I'm lacking more detailed information.

Comment: In $PATH  i also have anaconda3/condabin but the commands like anaconda navigator and jupyter notebook are in anaconda3/bin so i am getting the error command not found.

Comment: /home/YOUR_USER/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin